# jQuery autocomplete and locally fetched json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am struggling with jQuery UI Autocomplete and reading the autocomplete values from a variable that stores all the data returned from a json array. This is what the JavaScript looks like:

```
function populate_branch(){
     $.get('/branch/list', {bank_name : $("#select_bank_name").val()}, function(branch_data){
        branch_index = branch_data;
     },"json");
};

for( var i = 0; i < branch_index.length; i++ )
  branch_autocomplete += "" + "\'" + branch_index[i].branch_code + "\'" + "},";

$("#branch_auto_complete").autocomplete({
            source: branch_autocomplete
});
```

What happens when I try use the auto complete textbox my console does something very weird, it returns this:

> //localhost:3000/undefined%7B'label':'301105'%7D,%7B'label':'301205'%7…'label':'639625'%7D,%7B'label':'639845'%7D,%7B'label':'639948'%7D,?term=41
>   404 (Not Found)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to make this work,

```
var branch_index;
var branch_autocomplete, branch_name;
var index_branch_code = new Array();
function populate_branch(){
     $.get('/branch/list', {bank_name : $("#select_bank_name").val()}, function(branch_data){
        branch_index = branch_data;
        for( var i = 0; i <  branch_index.length; i ++ )
        {
            index_branch_code[i] = branch_index[i].branch_name + " ("  + branch_index[i].branch_code + ")";
        }
     },"json");
};

$("#branch_auto_complete").autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: branch_code,
});
```

I just needed to push all the data into an array and create a new variable that is equal to index_branch_code so that the browser sees the variable as a flat file instead of it being dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and this way.

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/branch/list',
     type: "GET",
     data: {bank_name : $("#select_bank_name").val()} ,
     dataType: "json",
     async: false,
     success: function(dataType) { 

          for( var i = 0; i <  branch_index.length; i ++ ){
              index_branch_code[i] = branch_index[i].branch_name + " ("+ branch_index[i].branch_code + ")";
          }

         $("#branch_auto_complete").autocomplete({
              minLength: 0,
              source: branch_code,
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: /branch/list is a json array generated from my database. Thats just the path to the data. It would look like http://localhost:3000/branch/list.js

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @interjay my intention was not to criticize. i didn't know how to comment right above his question because the `comment` button doesn't appears. i suppose i just have to use  `edit` button.  sorry for misunderstanding